# Do One to Many relationship to self class in ObjectBox cause entire tree loads?

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I am trying to model a tree-like data structure in ObjectBox, where each node in the tree has some contents.

However, in reading the [tutorial](http://objectbox.io/documentation/relations/) it says:

> Note that to-many relations are resolved lazily on the first request, and then
>   cached in the source entity inside the ToMany object.

Does this mean that if I have a huge tree structure and load the top-level node, it is going to resolve the whole tree under a node?  If so, is it smart about memory usage so I don't run out of memory if the tree is huge?  If I have several fields, some of which can be large, does it load all of them when I reference the node, or does it only load the parts of the node I ask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be describing "eager loading". On the contrary, ObjectBox defaults to "lazy loading" that only loads data once you access them.

If you are concerned about memory usage for cached fields, you can clear cached values using `reset()`.